# Csv data could not be loaded in c3 chart

Tags: c3.js

This is the javascript file which is added in html file.I Tried using all possible paths but still this is not working. Thanks in advance

```
<div id="chart"></div>
<script>
var chart = c3.generate({
data: {
    url: 'data.csv',
    type: 'bar'
},
bar: {
    width: {
        ratio: 0.5
    }
},
axis: {rotated : true}
});
</script>
```

Comment: the data.csv file is in same folder containing html file

Comment: you use some chartId in your html but you don't bind your chart to an id like `bindto: 'chart'` . if it still does not work can you provide some more information? how do you add this file in your html, how does your cvs look like, do you get any errors?

Comment: i kept above code in html file within <script> tag